# on("click", event) firing without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

**There are similar questions on this topic but their answers didnt work for my problem.**

Im trying to use jQuery's `on("click")` to fire a function that simply changes the class of the id which was clicked. But the function is called when the page is loaded and then if you click on what should fire the function it wont.

Here is the html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="all" class="tab-current"><a><span>All Departments</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here the js:

```
var $all = $("#all");
$all.on("click", function(){
    tabClicked("all");
});
```

I've also tried this:

```
$all.on("click", tabClicked("all"));
```

And this is the function:

```
function tabClicked(input){
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: `$(function)` is shorthand for `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $all = $("#all");

$all.on("click", function(){
    tabClicked("all");
});
```

Try editing it like this. `$(function() {});` is like `$(document).ready()`, so put `function(){}` instead of `$(function() {});`.

EDIT:

For some reason, it is firing if `script` tag is after elements in html. I tried your code with external JS and etc. - didn't work.

Try like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9jym50e/)

EDIT 2: You should put your handler in `$(document).ready()` function anywhere you want, that's the reason.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var $all = $("#all");
 $all.on("click", function(){
    alert("click");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an error in your click handler logic; you just need to pass an anonymous function to the handler:

```
$all.on("click", function(){
    tabClicked("all");
});
```

Your original `$(function() {});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready()` hence it was immediately executed, regardless of whether the element had been clicked.

Comment: I doubt it will throw any syntax error..Edit: It will once `click` is invoked..

Comment: That is not fired when page is load, but wont fire either when clicked...

Comment: @PabloDuque this should work fine. Check the console in your page for other errors.

Comment: @RayonDabre true, it's a syntax error in the sense that it's not the right syntax for the required behaviour, not that it is an actual error. Updated the answer to be clearer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Im afraid it does not work.... and there are no erroes in the console. I've followed the execution and the function is never called

Comment: As you can see this works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6au8zf9g/. The only way I can see this would not work is if you have multiple elements all with the same `id` of `all`, which is invalid HTML and you should change them to be a class instead.

Comment: I know its a simple action and it should work thats why I came here since I've reviewed every little detail I know and still wont work. No, IDs I've used are all unique

Comment: In that case there's not much anyone can do with the information you've given us, as it should be working fine. If you could setup your own http://jsfiddle.net with a demonstration of the actual behaviour you're seeing

Answer (score 1):

replace $(function() to function ()

Comment: That is not fired when page is load, but wont fire either when clicked...

Comment: why is var $all = $("#all"); When you can directly add it in function statemnt   $( "#all" ).on( "click", function() {
  tabClicked("all") ;
});

Comment: well I use it multiple times and its shorter to call it by just $all. But that is not the problem here

Comment: Please recheck the code.Why because i  just  replaced function () code in my local, its working fine!

Comment: I've rechecked it multiple times... no success